How to optionally capture a path segment in Haskell servant?
I need to introduce a internalization in my servant app in a backward compatible manner. I want to have the language code as an optional path segment. If the very first path segment is from a known list of language codes, that language is used, else it defaults to Nothing (which the handler/server would interpret as some default language).
/some/path => myHandler Nothing
/en/some/path => myHanddler (Just "en")
/fr/some/path => myHandler (Just "fr")

To avoid having to write the following boilerplate...

Each endpoint will have two endpoints: one with the language code segment, and one without
Therefore, the server/handler will also need to have two variants -- one with language code and one without

...I wanted to come up with a servant combinator that "peeks" at head $ pathInfo req and it if looks like a language-code, it captures it, else it passes along Nothing to the sub-server.
I came up with the following, but this is not working, because it always expects pathSegment to be present. It is not capturing it on an optional basis.
data HostWithLocale = HostWithLocale

instance (HasServer api context) => HasServer (HostWithLocale :> api) context where
  type ServerT (HostWithLocale :> api) m = (Hostname, Maybe LanguageCode) -> ServerT api m
  
  hoistServerWithContext _ pc nt s = hoistServerWithContext (Proxy :: Proxy api) pc nt . s  

  route _ context server = 
    CaptureRouter [hint] $ route (Proxy :: Proxy api) context subserver
    where
      hint = CaptureHint "language" (typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy (Hostname, Maybe LanguageCode)))
      subserver = addCapture server $ \pathSegment -> withRequest $ \req -> 
        case DL.lookup (fromString "Host") (requestHeaders req) of
          Nothing -> 
            delayedFail err406
          Just hname -> 
            if Prelude.not (isWhiteListedDomain hname)
              then delayedFail err406
              else if pathSegment `DL.elem` knownLanguageCodes
                then pure $ (toS hname, Just $ LanguageCode pathSegment)
                else pure $ (toS hname, Nothing)

isWhiteListedDomain :: C8.ByteString -> Bool
isWhiteListedDomain = undefined 
    
knownLanguageCodes :: [Text]
knownLanguageCodes = undefined


Another approach could be adding an optional parameter to each endpoint in the API.

Optional query param is one way to go, but most people recommend either putting the language code in the path, or as a subdomain.


Therefore, the server/handler will also need to have two variants -- one with language code and one without

Those two variants can be defined without much duplication, and without having to define new HasServer instances.
Imagine that you have a SomeApi type that corresponds to a Servant API definition. It might be very complex, have many routes, whatever. The type of a value that can serve that API will be Server SomeApi.
Suppose that now we define this API that captures a language path segment:
type SomeApiI18n = Capture "lang" Text :> SomeApi

That API can be served by values of type Server SomeApiI18n. But, if we expand the Server type family application a little, that type will be equivalent to Text -> Server SomeApi.
Now suppose we have a value someServerI18n of type Text -> Server SomeApi and want to serve SomeApi (the non-localized version) with it. How? Very easy, we simply apply a default language:
someServer' :: Server SomeApi
someServer' = someServerI18n "en"

Now, suppse you have a combined API like
type FullApi = SomeApi :<|> SomeApiI18n

It can be served like this:
fullApiServer :: Server FullApi
fullApiServer = someServerI18N "en" :<|> someServerI18N

No need to tweak every route in SomeApi, or to define two completely different server implementations.
